# If statement issues, not displaying correct output

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that gives the user options to select from a list of measurements they would like to convert.
So far my code I have is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int sv, SourceUnit, du, mb, kb, by;
    printf("--------------------------------------------------0x0 Menu:------    ---------------------------------\n");
    printf(" Please Select from the following options (enter number exactly when prompted for source units!\n");
    printf("1: Kilo -> Mega\n2: Mega -> Kilo\n10. Bits -> Bytes\n ");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Enter source value: ");
    scanf("%d", &sv);

    printf("Enter source unit: ");
    scanf("%s", &SourceUnit);

    if (SourceUnit == 1)                                                            //convert kilobytes to megabytes
    {

        mb = (sv / 1024);
        printf("%d Kb ==  %d Mb\n", sv, mb);
    }

    else if (SourceUnit == 2)                                                           //convert megabytes to kilobytes
    {
        kb = (sv / 1024);
        printf("%d Mb == %d Kb\n", sv, kb);
    }

    else if (SourceUnit == 10)                                                          //bits to bytes
    {
        by = (sv / 8);
        printf("%d Bits == %d Bytes\n", sv, by);
    }

    else 
    {
        printf("Please Choose from the menu options to convert!\n");
    }

    return(0);
}
```

It compiles fine on GCC. The output I am getting is:

```
---------------------------------------0x0 Menu:----------------------------
1. Kilo -> Mega
2. Mega -> Kilo
3. Bits -> Bytes
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enter Source Value: (Example I will type in 30 for the number to be converted) 30
Enter Source Unit: (Example will be 1 to convert from Kilo to Mega) 1
Please Choose from the menu options to convert!
```

For some reason my else statement is showing up when I do not want it to..what is causing this error?

Also I am having some issues I need to convert a deka to a dibi..how exactly can that be done?
I know a deka is a group of 10 and a dibi is a group of 16 but that is all the information I can read up on them..

Comment: Why did you use %d for the 1st int and %s for the 2nd?

Comment: gcc output: "temp.c:17:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’", why you didn't read it?

Comment: well, No, it does not 'compile fine on gcc'  When compiling always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc` at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )  This results in two warnings 1) unused variable: `du` 2) on line 17,`scanf("%s", &SourceUnit);` format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*' but argument 2 has type 'int *'  That incorrect argument type is a major problem that needs to be corrected.  Perhaps you meant: `scanf("%d", &SourceUnit);`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: strongly suggest the logic sequences `if/else if/else if/else` be replaced with a `swtich() statement that includes a `defautl` case to handle invalid inputs.`

Comment: scenario: user input 500, then inputs 1.   The output will be: `500 Kb == 0 Mb` which is not really correct.  Suggest using float values, so the output would be: `500 Kb == .5 Mb`

Comment: Suggest placing the majority of the `main()` function in aloop so the user can try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scanf is having wrong format specifier. It should have been "%d". That caused the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int sv, SourceUnit, du, mb, kb, by;
    printf("--------------------------------------------------0x0 Menu:------    ---------------------------------\n");
    printf(" Please Select from the following options (enter number exactly when prompted for source units!\n");
    printf("1: Kilo -> Mega\n2: Mega -> Kilo\n10. Bits -> Bytes\n ");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Enter source value: ");
    scanf("%d", &sv);

    printf("Enter source unit: ");
    scanf("%d", &SourceUnit); //This should be %d

    if (SourceUnit == 1)                                                            //convert kilobytes to megabytes
    {

        mb = (sv / 1024);
        printf("%d Kb ==  %d Mb\n", sv, mb);
    }

    else if (SourceUnit == 2)                                                           //convert megabytes to kilobytes
    {
        kb = (sv / 1024);
        printf("%d Mb == %d Kb\n", sv, kb);
    }

    else if (SourceUnit == 10)                                                          //bits to bytes
    {
        by = (sv / 8);
        printf("%d Bits == %d Bytes\n", sv, by);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Please Choose from the menu options to convert!\n");
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Jeez. Silly mistake. Thank you!